Debian 12 bootable USB
I bought new MSI motherboard B670 Tomahawk with AMD Ryzen 7800X3D. I want to install Debian 12 on this machine. For last 15 years I was doing this the same way:

Download bootable ISO
Check checksum
Create bootable USB with dd
Install the system

However now I am struggling. First dd does not create a bootable USB for the first time I had to create it with UNetBootin. New PC sees the bootable, but refuses to boot. When I get to boot menu a select boot from USB screen flashes and returns back. This USB, however, worked on other PC. Then I tried third option I install Debian 11 surprisingly this worked. But distro upgrade failed because some packages could not be configured.
What am I doing wrong. I know non-free firmware is now part of the distro is this somehow related?

the part where debian loads non-free firmware is not reached if the thing refuses to boot.

This smells like either problems with the USB stick, or some trouble with the firmware of your board. Try disabling "Legacy Boot" or "BIOS boot" in the firmware setup. Make sure you've downloaded the right architecture (amd64). I would not use unetbootin on a modern machine. I'd personally would also not use dd but simply cat or cp the file to the device; see https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s03.en.html

@MarcusMüller In BIOS there is no Legacy option. I seams only UEFI is possible. I bought a new USB stick (lost the old one) cheapest option in the local grocery store, in deed when you are mentioning it the stick is strange, first of all it is USB 2, I was not aware they are still making those. Since I can boot Debian 11 I can try also update board firmware. thx.

really make sure you've written the image to the whole stick, and not just to a partition of it

The cheapest option of USB stick is often a fake (features far below the specification). I suggest that you buy a USB stick of a well-known brand or even an SSD connected via USB.

In BIOS there is no Legacy option. I seams only UEFI is possible - often called something with CSM in it ... CSM Boot, or Enable CSM - also, if "Secure Boot" is enabled it may be a problem.

@MarcusMüller Updating MTB firmware did the job. If you write an answer I will accept it.

@Addman I'll let yo do that – self-answering questions is highly welcome here, and you really did all the hard work! I didn't even suggest updating, I just said "might be trouble with…", so all the actually good ideas came from you :)

The problem disappeared after I update the latest motherboard firmware. I highly recommend to update motherboard firmware right after the purchase and periodically as new updates are emerging (obviously).
